# What do the lines on a Feynman diagram represent?

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams

I know that the lines do not represent the paths of the particles, so what do they represent, please?

I have looked on the Wikipedia article, but it seems confusing that particles can move backwards in time - surely if they are colliding, they would move forwards towards the point at which they collide. The image on Wikipedia shows a positron moving backwards from the collision. I am also confused by the probability amplitude - I have seen websites discussing it in terms of complex numbers.

Update: From what I have seen so far, I'm getting the impression that these lines represent possibilities for decay (I think that's what decay channels are?), but I am still not sure about why some particles move against time.

Update 2: The idea that the lines represent probabilities and that we can multiply probabilities on each line to give a total probability for the whole event makes me think that this is like a probability tree.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Have you done any research or otherwise tried to figure out the answer yourself? We like people to have [put some effort into their questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5778), including searching the web, looking at the relevant Wikipedia pages and other resources, and tried any relevant calculations or logical reasoning before asking here.

Comment: You should not think about the Feynman diagrams as they represent some part of the real process. They are  a visualization of the calculation of possible deacy channels (and orders of pertubation theory).  There are certain rules to draw them which correspends to certain rules of finding the possible decay channels and their orders of pertubation theory.

Comment: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram is useful, bearing in mind the above comments regarding self research and not taking the lines in any literal sense.

Comment: @Alpha001 I think that shouldn't have been posted as a comment, though perhaps as an answer.

Comment: @DavidZ Thanks - I have tried to include a bit more detail on what I have looked at so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most applications especially in experimental physics you can think of the lines as particle trajectories in time and 1D Space. All particles travel forward in time, you might refer to the [Feynman-Stueckelberg-Interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiparticle#Feynman.E2.80.93Stueckelberg_interpretation) where particles with negative Energy are interpreted as particles moving backwards in time but this is just an interpretation and it can also be seen as an anti-particle traveling forward in time.
An Example:

[image]

This is one possible feynman-Diagram of infinitely many ones describing two electrons scattering. Sum all the possible Diagrams up and square them, integrating them over the phase space and you will get the Probability for this process to happen.

More carefully is a Feynman-Diagram the symbolic expression of the scattering amplitudes in a quantum field theory for one possible process and at a specific pertubation order. The lines are the "propagators" for the specific theory you are considering which can be calculated from the lagrangian of the theory. So when people draw a feynmandiagram they actually write down a algebraically complex formula.

Comment: The latter part of your answer is correct, but the introductory sentence, while many may say so colloquially, is just completely false. A Feynman diagram does *not* depict trajectories of *anything*, and saying so is not simply less accurate, but plainly wrong.

Comment: Hm i might have formulated this more carefully. It is of course in deed possible to extract informations about possible final states from some initial state by drawing all feynman diagrams at a specific perturbation order. So knowing that internal lines are virtual, allows to interpret feynman diagrams as a possible process for this interaction to happen. I didn't state that feynman diagrams depict trajectories. I said that it is sometimes, especially at the beginning, helpful to think about them as this.